# Git: show all commits on a given weekday

Tags: git, git-log

Can I see all of the commits which were made on a Sunday? Any and all Sundays, to be clear.

Answer (score 7):

Based on jingx's answer, the following will give you a log of all commits made on a Sunday.

```
git log --pretty='format:%h %cd' | grep 'Sun' |  awk '{print $1}' | while read rev; do
    git show $rev | head -6
done
```

**Explanation**

`git log --pretty='format:%h %cd'` gives a shortened log of all commits with their SHAs and commit dates. These dates contain day of the week as well.

`grep 'Sun'` filters out all lines of that log with 'Sun' on it, i.e., all commits made on Sundays.

`awk '{print $1}'` extracts the first word of each of these lines, i.e. the SHA values of each commit.

`while read rev` loops through each SHA value extracted from the previous `awk`. At each iteration, the SHA value will be stored in the `rev` variable.

`git show $rev` shows the log of the commit with the SHA `$rev`.

`head -6` extracts the first 6 lines of that log.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
git log --pretty='format:%h %cd' |grep Sun
```

Answer (score 1):

**jingx**'s answer is correct, upvoted!

I just would like to mention that at some point I also wanted to retrieve the same kind of specificity, like any and all commits done:

- on the `-9 GMT` hour
- on the `33rd` second
- on `Fri 13th`
- on `1337` files
- with `777` *impact* (`insertions` - `deletions`)

...and found `git log` interface a bit lacking. But the data is there!

I created therefore https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg, which parses commits of any number of repositories into one conveniently sanitised `JSON` file. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
--since and --until
```

key for `git log` command.